# How can i add an MDDataTable within scrollview?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have a scrollview in my kivy app and i amtrying to add an mddatatable from the python file onto a float layout within the scrollview.The datatable shows up but its compressed such that there is no data being shown to the user.

I have tried adjusting the height of the floatlayout and even changing the layout to a box layout but nothing seems to work.The python file

```
def sales_table(self):
         
         headers=["ID","SIZE","PRICE (Ksh)","Quantity"]
         self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM maji_mazuri.catalogue")
         result = self.cursor.fetchall()
         row_data = [] 
         for row in result:
            row_data.append(row)
        
         self.mytable_catalogue=MDDataTable(
            size_hint=(.9,.9),
            pos_hint= {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.7},
            check=True,
            use_pagination=True,
            pagination_menu_height="240dp",
            elevation=3,

            column_data=[(header, dp(30)) for header in headers],
            row_data=row_data
        )
         layout=self.ids.sales_layout
         self.mytable_catalogue.bind(on_check_press=self.on_check_press2)
         layout.add_widget(self.mytable_catalogue)
```

The KV file mainly focus on the FloatLayout at the bottom

```
MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'sales'
                text: 'Sales'
                icon: 'cash-check'
                icon_size: "36dp"

                ScrollView:
                    size:self.size
                    do_scroll_x: False


                    GridLayout:
                        size_hint_y:None
                        height:self.minimum_height
                        width:self.minimum_width
                        cols:1
                        spacing:"30dp"
                        padding:"20dp"
                        
                        MDLabel:
                            text:"SALES ENTRY"
                            theme_text_color:"Custom"
                            text_color: 21/255,39/255,112/255,1
                            
                            halign:"center"
                            font_size:"45sp"
                            font_style:"H4"
                        BoxLayout:
                            size_hint:.9,None
                            height:self.minimum_height
                            
                            spacing:"15dp"

                            MDTextField:
                                id:sales_entry
                                mode:"fill"
                                hint_text:"Enter Sale"
                                size_hint_x: 1
                                font_size:"18dp"
                                on_text:root.sales_input_check()
                                
                            MDRaisedButton:
                                id:submit_sales
                                text:"Submit"
                                disabled:False
                                size_hint_x: 1
                                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                                font_size:"18dp"
                                on_press: 

                        FloatLayout:
                            id:sales_layout
                            size_hint:.9,None
```

Comment: I cannot run your code, but I suspect your problem involves the `height:self.minimum_height` of your `GridLayout`. If you use `minimum_height`, then the children of the `GridLayout` must provide a `height` that can be used to calculate the minimum height. The `size_hint` will not provide a usable height.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would it be possible to adjust the height of each grid manually? And especially the grid that contains the FloatLayout

Comment: No, you can set the height of a row, or the width of a column. Perhaps you should try a different `Layout` if you need more control.

Comment: Ok.I decided to just use different screens to display the tables